# How converts list objects to JSON in gvnix

Tags: json, spring-mvc, spring-roo, gvnix

Hi I´m developing new controllers over GVNIX development tool but I don´t understand how it is transforming object list to JSON.

I have seen in the GEO example, the entities list are working with DataTables and the ajax filter it´s working with JSON. The database access are in BatchService that returns object list, but I havent found where the controller get´s this list and returns the JSON.

Can anybody help me to understand how it´s working ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The conversion is handle by Spring Web MVC based on `@RequestMapping` and `@ResponseBody` annotations value through Jaskson Library. ([This post](http://www.beingjavaguys.com/2014/05/json-response-with-responsebody_31.html) talk about it)

In addition, as standard *Spring MVC Jackson* converter doesn't use the ApplicationConversionService Bean, gvNIX includes a custom converter that uses this bean to serialize and bind some object (as Spring do in standard POST request). You can found this configuration in `webmvc-config.xml` file:

```
<bean class="org.gvnix.web.json.Jackson2RequestMappingHandlerAdapter" 
    id="dataBinderRequestMappingHandlerAdapter" p:order="1">
        <property name="objectMapper">
            <bean class="org.gvnix.web.json.ConversionServiceObjectMapper"/>
        </property>
</bean>
```

*Note*: `Jackson2RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` only handles request which `@RequestMapping` propierties `produces` and `consumes` is set to `application/json`

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @jmvivo I understand how it ´s working now!. Do you know if there is an easy way to get GeoJSON instead of JSON to be handled by leaflet ?.

Comment: To archive this you should implement your own serializer  (you could use  the Jackson interface). Then, implement a request on Controller that use it (if you get Spring serialization problems, serialize the list yourself and return a String). If you do it, will be a good point to share it with the community ;-).

Comment: If you think that this is the right answer, please, click check mark. Thank you.